# Blank image after resizing in canvas

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to resize an image using the canvas method. I am then getting the ArrayBuffer and using that to upload the new image. Here's my resize method.

```
function resizeImage(img) {
  var perferedWidth = 160;
  var ratio = perferedWidth / img.width;
  var $canvas = $("#canvasTest");
  var canvas = $("#canvasTest")[0];
  canvas.width = img.width * ratio;
  canvas.height = img.height * ratio;
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
  var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height).data.buffer;
  return imageData;
}
```

The problem is once the image gets uploaded, it's just a blank image. I am not doing something correct as the imageData is not giving me a valid buffer. I know it's not valid because when I convert the imageData to a base64 string, it's not a valid base64 encoded image (image doesn't show up when I set its src to it).

I also know that the `drawImage` method is working, as I have temporarily created a canvas in the DOM and it is correctly drawing the image to that canvas.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: How are you converting the `ArrayBuffer` to a base64 image?

Comment: @Cristy I can show the function if you think you need it, but I do know the function works correctly as I tried using it with a few different images (before resizing) and they all displayed correctly.